# Stored procedure is taking too much time to update the table columns

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have created a stored procedure which is taking too much of time to update the columns of the table. Say 3 hrs to update 2.5k records out of 43k records.

So can I reduce the time of updating the records. Below is my logic for the same.

```
procedure UPDATE_MST_INFO_BKC
  (
    P_SAPID IN NVARCHAR2
  )
  as
  v_cityname varchar2(500):='';
  v_neid varchar2(500):='';
  v_latitude varchar2(500):='';
  v_longitude varchar2(500):='';
  v_structuretype varchar2(500):='';
  v_jc_name varchar2(500):='';
  v_jc_code varchar2(500):='';
  v_company_code varchar2(500):='';
  v_cnt number :=0;
  
  begin
  select count(*) into v_cnt from structure_enodeb_mapping where  RJ_SAPID=P_SAPID  and rownum=1;
  
  if v_cnt > 0 then 
  begin
  
   select RJ_CITY_NAME, RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID,LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE,RJ_JC_NAME,RJ_JC_CODE,'6000' 
   into v_cityname,v_neid,v_latitude, v_longitude, v_structuretype,v_jc_name,v_jc_code,v_company_code from structure_enodeb_mapping where RJ_SAPID=P_SAPID  and rownum=1;

        update tbl_ipcolo_mast_info set 
        
        CITY_NAME                   = v_cityname,
        NEID                        = v_neid,
        FACILITY_LATITUDE           = v_latitude,
        FACILITY_LONGITUDE          = v_longitude,
        RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE           = v_structuretype,
        RJ_JC_NAME                  = v_jc_name,  
        RJ_JC_CODE                  = v_jc_code,  
        COMPANY_CODE                = v_company_code
        where SAP_ID=P_SAPID;
  
  end;
  end if;   

  end UPDATE_MST_INFO_BKC;
```

What adjustments can I make to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your code, It is updating `TBL_IPCOLO_MAST_INFO` having `SAP_ID = P_SAPID` Means It is updating one record and you must be calling the procedure for each record.

It is a good practice of calling the procedure once and update all the record in one go. (In your case 2.5k records must be updated in one call of this procedure only)

For your requirement, Currently, I have updated the procedure code to only execute MERGE statement, which will be same as multiple SQLs in your question for single `P_SAPID`.

```
PROCEDURE UPDATE_MST_INFO_BKC (
    P_SAPID IN   NVARCHAR2
) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO TBL_IPCOLO_MAST_INFO I 
    USING (
            SELECT
                RJ_CITY_NAME,
                RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID,
                LATITUDE,
                LONGITUDE,
                RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE,
                RJ_JC_NAME,
                RJ_JC_CODE,
                '6000' AS COMPANY_CODE,
                RJ_SAPID
            FROM
                STRUCTURE_ENODEB_MAPPING
            WHERE
                RJ_SAPID = P_SAPID
                AND ROWNUM = 1
            )
    O ON ( I.SAP_ID = O.RJ_SAPID )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET I.CITY_NAME = O.RJ_CITY_NAME,
                I.NEID = O.RJ_NETWORK_ENTITY_ID,
                I.FACILITY_LATITUDE = O.LATITUDE,
                I.FACILITY_LONGITUDE = O.LONGITUDE,
                I.RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE = O.RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE,
                I.RJ_JC_NAME = O.RJ_JC_NAME,
                I.RJ_JC_CODE = O.RJ_JC_CODE,
                I.COMPANY_CODE = O.COMPANY_CODE;

END UPDATE_MST_INFO_BKC;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: `Error(1102,23): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "O"."RJ_SAPID": invalid identifier` has error

Comment: Ohh, Yes... I have updated the answer now!! Please check

Comment: It will update the table `TBL_IPCOLO_MAST_INFO ` using values from `STRUCTURE_ENODEB_MAPPING` on condition when `I.SAP_ID = O.RJ_SAPID`

Comment: Can you please let me know how you are using this procedure?

Comment: I am using this procedure to update one by one record based on `sap_id` in a for loop from  my code

Comment: No, you need to directly provide some mechanism to only use this merge starement once. Which will save lots of the time. If you are calling it for each sap_id then it will definately takes time

Answer (score 1):

3 hours? That's way too much. Are `sap_id` columns indexed? Even if they aren't, data set of 43K rows is just too small.

How do you call that procedure? Is it part of another code, perhaps some unfortunate `loop` which does something row-by-row (which is, in turn, slow-by-slow)?

A few objections:

- are all those variables' datatypes really `varchar2(500)`? Consider declaring them so that they'd take table column's datatype, e.g. `v_cityname structure_enodeb_mapping.rj_city_name%type;`. Also, there's no need to explicitly say that their value is null (`:= ''`), it is so by default
- `select` statement which checks whether there's something in the table for that parameter's value should be rewritten to use `EXISTS` as it should perform better than `rownum = 1` condition you used.

  - also, consider using exception handlers (`no-data-found` if there's no row for a certain ID; `too-many-rows` if there are two or more rows)
- `select` statement that collects data into variables has the same condition; do you really expect more than a single row for each ID (passed as a parameter)?

Anyway, the whole procedure's code can be shortened to a single `update` statement:

```
update tbl_ipcolo_mst_info t set
  (t.city_name, t.neid, ...) = (select s.rj_city_name, 
                                       s.rj_network_entity_id, ...
                                from structure_enodeb_mapping s
                                where s.rj_sapid = t.sap_id
                               )
where t.sap_id = p_sapid;
```

If there is something to be updated, it will be. If there's no matching `t.sap_id`, nothing will happen.

Comment: Thanks Mate for your so fast reply..yes I am updating it row by row as mentioned by you. So can I try your short little answer and check ?

Comment: You're welcome. Try it, see what happens. Don't commit if it doesn't work as expected!

Comment: Nothing much; fixed invalid formatting, as pure text was formatted as code.